# Python matrices calculations - dot product

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have array vector where I am trying to calculate the dot product between the two, however I am getting the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-d458314e2348> in <module>
     13 # wavelength
     14 lam = frequency/c
---> 15 baseline_length = np.array([np.sin(HA), np.cos(HA), 0],
     16                                [-np.sin(dec_ang)*np.cos(HA), np.sin(dec_ang)*np.sin(HA), np.cos(dec_ang)],
     17                                [np.cos(dec_ang)*np.cos(HA), -np.cos(dec_ang)*np.sin(HA), np.sin(dec_ang)])

TypeError: array() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Here is my code;

```
#positions of the first and second antenna of shape (n,3)
ant1, ant2  =  np.empty((0,3)), np.empty((0,3))
    
#convert the hour angle to radians
HA = 1.5*2*math.pi/24
#convert the declination angle to radians
dec_ang = 45*math.pi/180
#convert the frequency to hertz
frequency = 2*10**9
#calculate the baseline
baseline = ant2 - ant1
#speed of light in m/s
c = 3*math.pow(10, 8)
# wavelength
lam = frequency/c
baseline_length = np.array([np.sin(HA), np.cos(HA), 0],
                           [-np.sin(dec_ang)*np.cos(HA), np.sin(dec_ang)*np.sin(HA), np.cos(dec_ang)],
                           [np.cos(dec_ang)*np.cos(HA), -np.cos(dec_ang)*np.sin(HA), np.sin(dec_ang)])
        
u = np.sum(baseline_length[0]*baseline[0], axis=1) * lam
v = np.sum(baseline_length[1]*baseline[1], axis=1) * lam
```

in fact I could do it like with code below, but that will require me to write that down every time should I change my antenna dimensions

```
u = (np.sin(HA)*baseline[0] + np.cos(HA)*baseline[1]) * lam
v = (-np.sin(dec_ang)*np.cos(HA)*baseline[0] + np.sin(dec_ang)*np.sin(HA)*baseline[1] + np.cos(dec_ang)*baseline[2]) * lam
```

Comment: First, note that numpy does not use ```*``` as a dot product. Instead [numpy.dot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) must be used. Given that your question has 'dot product' in the title, and I do not see np.dot() in your code that seems off.
Second it seems that you are trying to turn something into a numpy array, that numpy does not like.  ```numpy.array( [ 0] , [1], [2] )```  will produce the same error.  Its not super clear what you are trying to do, but at first glance it seems you are missing some extra ```[``` ```]``` inside your numpy array casting.

Comment: I could do it using the `np.sum()` to at least something like the code of `u` and `v` I provided. however, that feels too much since I'd need to repeat it should I make minor changes

Comment: Pay closer attention to the error, and the function that raised it!  Did you review the docs for `np.array`?  It should be given **one** list, not 3.  The second argument, if given will be interpreted as `dtype`.  Anything else has have a keyword.  You didn't even get to the `dot` part of your code!

Answer (score 3):

In the definition of `baseline_length` start with two square brackets: `np.array([[np.sin(HA), ...], [...], [...]])`.  Otherwise you're not creating a 2D array.

Comment: this worked though am having another error on dimensions

Comment: hey great!  the best numpy debugging tool is ```print('thing shape : %s' % thing.shape)``` to make sure your shapes are conformable